# Overflow in C code

Tags: c

Can anyone explain to me why this code prints "error" ? This only appears for minimal value of integer.

```
int abs(int x) {
    int result = 0;
    if(x < 0)
        result = -1*x;
    else 
        result = x;

    return result;
}

int main() {

    printf("Testing abs... ");
    if (abs(-2147483648) != 2147483648)
        printf("error\n");
    else
        printf("success\n");
}
```

Comment: have you tried `int a = -2147483648; int b = 2147483648; printf("%d %d", a, b);`?

Answer (score 7):

Because for a 32 bit integer signed integer, using [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), the largest number you can store is `2147483647`.

The range is `-2147483648 2147483647`.

You must be careful - overflowing signed numbers is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The maximal value of a 32 bit integer is 2,147,483,647.

Answer (score 0):

put long instead of int. For bigger integers you will need long long. Google for the range that this types offer. Also for the comparison with a static number you must declare it like e.g. 8438328L

Comment: Using `long` won't help on 32-bit Linux, 32-bit OS X, or any flavor of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way integers are represented [(2's complement)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), if your `int` is 32 bits, `-2147483648` is its own negative.

After `-2147483648` is returned by your `abs()`, it is probably being compared as a `long`, 64-bit integer.  If the comparison were 32-bit, `2147483648` would be equivalent to `-2147483648`.  Perhaps if you turn on all warnings for your compiler, it will complain?

Answer (score 0):

The range of 32-bit signed integers is, as has been mentioned before -2147483648 (= -2<sup>31</sup>) to 2147483647 (= 2<sup>31</sup> - 1). In your `abs()` function, you have thus overflow of a signed integer, which is undefined behaviour (citation of standard to be inserted). Therefore anything could happen, but what actually happens is very probably that the result just wraps around, producing -2147483648 again. However, you compare that to the integer literal 2147483648, which does not fit into a 32-bit signed integer, hence, since it has no (n)signedness suffix, that literal has the next type in the list

1. `int`
2. `long int`
3. `long long int`

which can represent its value (if any). On 64-bit systems that could be `long int` or `long long int`, the former is typically the case on Linux, the latter, as far as I know on Windows, on 32-bit systems it's almost certainly `long long int`.

Then the `int` value -2147483648 is promoted to `long (long) int` and the tested condition is

```
if (-2147483648L != 2147483648L)  // or LL
```